# How to save css changes in developer tool in internet explorer for live web site

Tags: css, wordpress, web-developer-toolbar

I am  setting up a website to be live that is created in Wordpress. The problem here is that I am trying to save some CSS changes I made in developer/Inspector tab but I can't in Internet Explore.

Answer (score 0):

The inspector tab is just for **preview**. You can't save CSS attributes in there.

**Select** your CSS codes which you have just writed, open your `WordPress dashboard > Appearance > Additional CSS`. **Paste** into in this area.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for google chrome and install this
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/styleurl/emplcligcppnlalfjknjbanolhlnkmgp

this is cool stuff to view changed css.

Answer (score 0):

The developer tools of any browser do not have access to your wordpress account and therefor can not make any changes to the actual site, otherwise anyone could exploit it to modify/delete the contents/appearance of your site.

As previous answer stated add the CSS you changed as Additional CSS in your WP dashboard.